# Project Euler #4 Largest Palindrome Product

Tags: java

We are trying to find the largest palindrome number that is generated by multiplying two 3-digit numbers. A palindrome number is one that reads the same from both sides (example: 12345654321 or simply 9009).
The following code compiles correctly, but clearly there is a logic error because the output is 749947 when it should be 906609. If anyone could help explain the logic of where I am getting this problem wrong that would be great.

```
boolean valid = false;
for (int i = 999*999; i > 100*100; i--) {
  if (i / 100000 == i % 10 &&
      i / 10000 % 10 == i / 10 % 10 &&
      i / 1000 % 10 == i / 100 % 10) {
        int buffer = i;
        int total = 1;
        for (int k = 2; k < buffer; k++) {
          if (buffer % k == 0) {
            buffer /= k;
            total *=k;
          }
        }
        if (buffer >= 100 && buffer < 1000 && total >=100 && total < 1000 ) {
          System.out.println(i);
          System.out.println(total);
          System.out.println(buffer);
          break;
        }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when you *attached a debugger in your IDE and walked through the code line by line*?

Comment: without actually analyzing the litmus test you're using, i would ask, what is the purpose of the first line of code in the snippet you've pasted?  You don't set valid = true anywhere ....

Comment: another hint to test the logic in your litmus test is to try a simpler test first, like converting i into a String that is equal to itself reversed

Answer (score 0):

```
906609  =  3 * 11 * 83 * 331  =  2739 * 331  =  913 * 993  =  ...
```

Your code resolves to `buffer = 331, total = 2739`, which fails your `if` statement.

*Suggestion:* Instead of checking all numbers from 998001 to 10000 and try to find 3-digit values that result in the number when multiplied, use a double `for` loop of 3-digit numbers and find largest product that is also a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is easier to follow, and works.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Palindrome
{
  private static List<Integer> palindromes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    for (int i = 999; i > 99; i--)
    {
      for (int j = 999; j > 99; j--)
      {
        if (isPalendrome(i * j))
        {
          palindromes.add(i * j);
        }
      }
    }
    if (!palindromes.isEmpty())
    {
      Collections.sort(palindromes);
      System.out.println(palindromes.get(palindromes.size() - 1));
    }
  }

  private static boolean isPalendrome(int number)
  {
    char[] word = String.valueOf(number).toCharArray();
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = word.length - 1;
    while (i2 > i1)
    {
      if (word[i1] != word[i2])
      {
        return false;
      }
      ++i1;
      --i2;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should have been easier for you to explain having written the code, but we have to go back to the reasoning within it. The outer loop takes a brute force approach, checking all numbers for palindromic patterns, then applying an inner test.

That inner test is where things go awry. It's trying to be clever, but producing a logic error. What I see it trying to do is to factorize the number found into `buffer` and `total`, intended to be the two three-digit numbers. However, it only checks later that they are triple digit; they are calculated with no regard for this rule.

`k` is used as a potential factor to transfer from `buffer` to `total`. Each number is checked once, which excludes any number with square or higher power factors. More importantly in this case, they're checked from low to high, until `total` is no longer smaller than `buffer`. So what happens with 906609?

```
(%i1) factor(906609);
(%o1) 3 11 83 331
```

The algorithm settles on 3*11*83 * 331, but 3*11*83=2739 so wrong number of digits. The sought answer uses a different split of factors: 3*331 * 11*83. The factorisation approach is doable, but you'll need to check for groupings of factors that in turn produce triple digit products.